# when are aggregate functions executed in sql (like sum(),max().. etc)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

As per my  knowledge  group by clause is executed before the select statement.

So if we have a sum() function in a select statement,when is that function exactly executed?

for eg in the below query

```
select c1,sum(c2)
from table
group by c1;
```

is sum(c2) executed when the grouping takes place?If yes,then how does it know that it has to perform sum() and not anything else ,because group by happens before the select clause. Or is it something else?

Thank You!

Comment: so when group by clause is being executed does it go check the select statement to see which aggregate function(in our case sum() ) is to be executed for the group

Comment: A naive implementation could do the grouping with no knowledge of which aggregates would be applied, so long as it had some means of storing *multiple* values in a single column during that phase. So it could have "For group `a,1`, I have values `(4, 5, 9)` in column `c` and values `('D', 'J', 'K')` in column `d`". That would require some internal array-like data type. Not saying any implementation does that, but it's how grouping could be done separately from aggregation.

Comment: but that seems very inefficient?

Comment: @AADITHYAKRISHNAN - the point was to demonstrate that you could *easily* build a system where grouping and computing aggregates *are* separate activities. Because your question seemed to be based on an assumption that you *must* do both at the same time. As to efficiency, I couldn't say. It could easily be a viable strategy in *some* circumstances, and this again goes back to the idea that in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. And hopefully the optimizer will pick a not unreasonable strategy most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per my knowledge group by clause is executed before the select statement.

This is incorrect.  The only "ordering" implicit in an SQL statement is the logical order of interpretation of the query.  This specifies that identifiers are first interpreted based on the `FROM` clause, then the `WHERE` clause, and so on.

A `SELECT` statement describes the result set.  The SQL engine is free to produce the result set in whatever ways it sees fit.  This usually consists of two phases, the compilation phase and the optimization phase.  The interpretation of identifiers is in the compilation phase.

What actually gets executed is typically a directed-acyclic graph (DAG) of operations.  The query gets compiled into this structure.  Most databases support a method of seeing what actually gets executed, typically via an `explain` method.  The DAG can rearrange operations and even eliminate some (if they are not needed).

Comment: thanks, also  is there anyway to check the order of execution in sql server management studio 2008 r2

Comment: @AADITHYAKRISHNAN . . . You need to look at the execution plan, which you can do through SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions in SQL is executed after GROUP BY clause.